# Set alias with quotes and double quotes in command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I want to set an alias for the command:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh usr@ip -p 57022 ; expect password ; send "pass\n" ; interact'
```

but quotes from `alias alias_name=""` and from command doesn't like each other.

I tried combinations with `'`, `"` and `, but all of these failed.
How can I do that?

Comment: lol, no, I asked this question 10 months earlier

Comment: you are right, but the other one is more viewed & upvoted and has better answers - better to point people there from here than vice versa

Comment: cf https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/8131703 - *If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.* (sorry, no insult to your question, but the answers are better on the other one)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a function, instead of an alias:

```
function function_name() {

    expect -c 'spawn ssh usr@ip -p 57022 ; \
        expect password ; send "pass\n" ; interact'

}
```

So you can call `function_name`, and it will work just as fine as with an alias.

If you still want to use an alias, just escape the inner `"`'s:

```
alias alias_name="expect -c 'spawn ssh usr@ip -p 57022 ; expect password ; send \"pass\n\" ; interact'"
```

and it should work.

Comment: great, function works fine! quotes escaping failed (bash: !Ak\n\": event not found) thank you very much :)